# Do likes merge on merging two Facebook Pages

Tags: facebook-pages

If I merge two pages:

Page a = 100 likes and page b = 200 likes

will the resultant page have a total of 300 likes?

Does merging two pages notify the users who already liked any of those two pages about the merger of those pages?

Answer (score 1):

From[Can I merge 2 Facebook Pages?](https://www.facebook.com/help/249601088403018):

> If you have 2 Facebook Pages for the same thing, you may be able to merge them if:

```
You're an admin of both Pages
Your Pages have similar names and represent the same thing
Your Pages have the same address, if they have physical locations
```

> To merge your Pages:

```
Go to facebook.com/pages/merge
Select 2 Pages you want to merge and click Continue
Click Request Merge
```

> If you're unable to merge your Pages, it means that your Pages aren't eligible to be merged. If you see the option to request to merge your Pages, we'll review your request.
>
> If your Pages can be merged, the people who like your Pages and any check-ins will be combined, but posts, photos, reviews, ratings and the username will be deleted from the Page you merge. The Page you want to keep will remain unchanged, except for the addition of people who like the Page and check-ins that were merged from the other Page. The Page you don't want to keep will be removed from Facebook, and you won't be able to unmerge it.

Answer (score 0):

> *If I merge two pages, Page a = 100 likes and page b = 200 likes. Will resultant page have total 300 likes?*

Yes, if both pages do not have common Likes.

> *Does merging two pages notify the users who already liked any of those two pages about the merger of those pages?*

If you request a merge of Page A into Page B, all of the fans of Page A will be notified. This gives the users the option to unlike the Page.

Answer (score -1):

I just merge 2 pages one day ago but the likes are the same on the Primary page. The merged page has 198 likes.

Comment: Please read [answer] so as to improve your answer.